# In Orbeon Forms, how can I change the color of visited sections in nav-list?

Tags: css, orbeon, visited

How to change the color of visited section in nav-list(form-runner). I tried with this expression that work to invalid sections visited. I changed it to work with the case of visited section (valid or not).

```
orbeon .xbl-fr-wizard .fr-wizard-toc .nav > span > a:visited {
    color: #00ff40;
}
```

This expression didn't work.

Comment: Just noticing that there is still no answer on this one. Is this still a relevant questions?

Comment: i just created a wizard xbl with new class for visited section and after that i modified in the css .this question was resolved .thanks

Comment: Good, thanks for confirming.